# Prime number less than 501

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, primes

I am trying to find all the prime numbers greater than 2 and less than 501. Please refer to my code given below:

```
num = 501

x = int(input('Enter a number greater than 1: '))

if x > 1:
    for i in range(2, num):
        if x % i == 0:
            result = False
    else:
        result = True

    if result == True:
        print('Prime number.')
    else:
        print('Not a prime number.')
else:
    print('Not a prime number.')
```

I tried to run the code for two numbers being 19 and 99. When I put a "break statement" after the code given below, I get the result of "99: not a prime number" but "19, being a prime is printed as not prime" and vice versa.

```
if x % i == 0:
        result = False
        break
```

Please correct the above code to print the correct output.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of using trial division, it is much faster to use the Sieve of Eratosthenes, invented by a Greek mathematician over two thousand years ago:

```
def primes(n): # sieve of eratosthenes
    i, p, ps, m = 0, 3, [2], n // 2
    sieve = [True] * m
    while p <= n:
        if sieve[i]:
            ps.append(p)
            for j in range((p*p-3)/2, m, p):
                sieve[j] = False
        i, p = i+1, p+2
    return ps
```

This function returns a list of primes less than *n*, sieving only on odd numbers and handling 2 separately. If you prefer to generate the primes rather than returning a list, use this:

```
def primegen(start=0): # stackoverflow.com/a/20660551
    if start <= 2: yield 2    # prime (!) the pump
    if start <= 3: yield 3    # prime (!) the pump
    ps = primegen()           # sieving primes
    p = next(ps) and next(ps) # first sieving prime
    q = p * p; D = {}         # initialization
    def add(m, s):            # insert multiple/stride
        while m in D: m += s  #   find unused multiple
        D[m] = s              #   save multiple/stride
    while q <= start:         # initialize multiples
        x = (start // p) * p  #   first multiple of p
        if x < start: x += p  #   must be >= start
        if x % 2 == 0: x += p #   ... and must be odd
        add(x, p+p)           #   insert in sieve
        p = next(ps)          #   next sieving prime
        q = p * p             #   ... and its square
    c = max(start-2, 3)       # first prime candidate
    if c % 2 == 0: c += 1     # candidate must be odd
    while True:               # infinite list
        c += 2                #   next odd candidate
        if c in D:            #   c is composite
            s = D.pop(c)      #     fetch stride
            add(c+s, s)       #     add next multiple
        elif c < q: yield c   #   c is prime; yield it
        else: # (c == q)      #   add p to sieve
            add(c+p+p, p+p)   #     insert in sieve
            p = next(ps)      #     next sieving prime
            q = p * p         #     ... and its square
```

There is much more about primes at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com).

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken this will always return false for all numbers below 501 since when any inputed number will be divisible by itself.
You should also check if x != i.

Answer (score 0):

This will work :

```
import math   # This will import math module

def isprime(x):
    if x > 1:
        result = True
        for i in range(2, int(math.sqrt(x))+1 ):
            if ( x % i == 0):
                result = False
                break
        if ( result == True):
            print("Prime Number ")
        else:
            print("Not a Prime Number")
```

And do function call like:

```
 isprime(19)
```

Answer (score 0):

> Please correct the above code to print the correct output.

I believe the following is both a simplified and corrected version of your code:

```
number = int(input('Enter a number greater than 1: '))

if number > 1:
    for divisor in range(2, int(number ** 0.5) + 1):
        if number % divisor == 0:
            print('Not a prime number.')
            break
    else:  # no break
        print('Prime number.')
else:
    print('Not a prime number.')
```

This code works but is not optimal.  One simple optimization would be to handle 2/even as a special case and only divide by odd numbers starting at 3.  A significant optimization would be to switch to a sieve approach as @user448810 suggests.

The code you provided only tests one number per user input.  If you want to convert it to a loop that tests a *range* of numbers, say all numbers greater than 2 but less than 501, then we can do:

```
for number in range(3, 501):

    if number > 1:
        for divisor in range(2, int(number ** 0.5) + 1):
            if number % divisor == 0:
                print(number, 'is not a prime number.')
                break
        else:  # no break
            print(number, 'is a prime number.')
    else:
        print(number, 'is not a prime number.')
```